# Retrieving the top-level version from sub modules in Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

This is a version of the question posted in [Maven: retrieving the main module version from a sub-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948091/maven-retrieving-the-main-module-version-from-a-sub-module), but I can't figure out how to apply the answer. I'm trying this on Maven 3.6.3. I've posted the repository this can be played around with at [this GitHub project](https://github.com/veselov/maven-parent-version-test)

I have a top-level project:

```xml
<groupId>com.vps</groupId>
<artifactId>main-module</artifactId>
<version>5.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

There is another *multi-module* project that needs to be parented by this top-level project, and it has independent versioning from the top-level project.

The projects are not expected to be in the same repository, and are generally released independently of each other.

I want to declare a property that I can further use to refer to the version of this top-level project parent (say to pull in artifacts with the correct version):

```xml
<artifactId>auxiliary</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.vps</groupId>
    <artifactId>main-module</artifactId>
    <version>5.0</version>
</parent>
<properties>
  <main.version>${project.parent.version}</main.version>
</properties>
<modules><module>corelib</module></modules>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vps</groupId>
      <artifactId>main-module-1</artifactId>
      <version>${main.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Now, the sub-module is to pull and use the dependency:

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>com.vps</groupId>
  <artifactId>auxiliary</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>corelib</artifactId>
<properties>
<!-- this doesn't work 
  <main.version>${project.parent.parent.version}</main.version>
-->
</properties>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.vps</groupId>
     <artifactId>main-module-1</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If I set `main.version` as a reference to `${project.parent.version}` in the `auxiliary` POM, compilation of `corelib` fails because it tries to pull `com.vps:main-module-1:1.0`, which doesn't exist. I guess this is because the properties are resolved based on the effective POM being processed at the moment, and from there, the `${project.parent.version}` is the version of `corelib`'s parent.

If I override `main.version` in the `corelib` sub-module as `${project.parent.parent.version}`, I get an error saying that effective version computed for `com.vps:main-module-1` is `'${project.parent.parent.version}'`, and is invalid. I guess this means that the property cannot be resolved all together, but I can't quite understand why.

So, how do I reasonably (i.e. without hardcoding the top-level in both the parent definition and another property) refer to that top-level version value from descendant submodules?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51969067/424903) answer help you? Modern versions of maven have CI-friendly features, a revision version is one of those. It seems like that is what you are after.

Comment: @Gimby I'm sorry, I don't see how this could help me here. Use of `${revision}` is great for avoiding repeating the project versions within modules, but I can't see how it helps accessing arbitrary (and unpredictable) version values up the project ancestry chain.

Comment: Could you please make an example project on github or a like ...that would make it easier to discuss about the things. The first question is: Should all the modules released separately or in one go? Do those modules exist within a single directory structure (same git repository?) ?

Comment: ... by making a version which is actually not unpredictable. The chosen solution is not going to work because there simply is no property project.parent.parent.version. So the quest is for a built-in maven feature that allows you to do this.

Comment: I was able to get the root POM version with gmaven as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15962647/944849). I was not trying to use that in dependency management though, so I'm not sure it would work in this situation. Might be worth a shot.

Comment: @khmarbaise I've updated the question with these details.